# General question on why we need a.s. finite stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $\tau$ be a stopping time w.r.t a filtration $(F_n)_n$ and $(X_n)_n$ a discrete time martingale w.r.t the same filtration.

Usually in the exercises, in order to apply the optional stopping thm, we have to show that $$P(\tau < \infty)=1$$

Then, we are allowed to write $X_{n \wedge \tau} \rightarrow X_{\tau}$  a.s.

Indeed, since $\tau$ is finite, as $n$ gets larger and larger we have that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n > N: \tau< n$ and hence $$n \wedge \tau \rightarrow \tau$$

My questions then is:
**if $\tau = \infty$ a.s., why doesn't that hold?** I mean, I can't figure out what could be the value of $lim_{n} (n \wedge \tau)$

Comment: Please define $X_\tau$

Comment: $(X_n)_n$ is a generic martingale. In the exercises often we consider the stopped martinale $(X_{n \wedge \tau})_n$ and the we want to take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: That does not answer my question. How is $X_\tau$ defined? One possibility is that it is $(X_\tau)(\omega) := X_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$ and then you need to say what $X_\infty$ should be?

Comment: Yes for me $X_{\tau}$ is exactly what you wrote. But I can't understand what is $X_{\infty}$

Comment: I think that's why you need $\tau < \infty$ a.s., so you don't have to worry about $X_\infty$. Another possible definition is $X_\tau = \sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n I_{\{\tau = n\}}$ so basically this says that we define $X_\tau$ to be $0$ if $\tau = \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\tau = \infty$ a.s., we have $X_{\tau\land n} = X_n$ a.s. and this will not (necessarily) converge to $X_\tau$.

Comment: In your equality $n$ is fixed, so yes: $n \wedge \tau = n$ a.s.

But what happens if we take $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Anything can happen. $(X_n)_n$ doesn't even have to converge.

Comment: Okay, thanks. If I assume that, for instance, the stopped process is uniformly bounded (and $\tau$ is **not a.s. finite**), i.e. $X_{n \wedge \tau} < C$, then I know that the martingale converges a.s. and in $L^1$, by a convergence theorem. So the problem would be now that I'm not allowed to say that $X_{n \wedge \tau} \rightarrow X_{\tau}$ a.s., right?

Comment: In general you need that $\tau < \infty$ a.s. to conclude $X_{n \land \tau} \to X_\tau$ a.s.. If you don't have that you will run into problems.

Comment: Clear, thank you.

Comment: So the moral is that one always need to check at least the a.s. finitess of a  stopping time

Comment: Yes. That's right.